# Closed terminal window but failed to exit nano. Possible to resume editing?

Tags: nano

Attempting to edit a file and am told is being edited by PID 24324.
I am guessing that I closed an SSH window and failed to exit nano.

I don't remember what I was doing and it would be nice to resume the session. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The parent process of `nano` (that you closed) owned `nano`'s STDIN, STDOUT, and STDERR streams. When the parent process went away, these streams were closed, and all access to them was lost.

But read `man nano` about SIGHUP and SIGTERM signals. You can ask `nano` to save its buffer.

This type of problem is why I run `screen` with `ssh` sessions.